# vim-surround not working for me. s key deletes instead of surrounds

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Just installed the surround plugin.

New buffer, type Hello World. Say I want to surround that with quotes.

In normal mode, V to get into visual mode, s to get into surround

Except it doesn't, s deletes the entire line.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The default visual mode mapping of surround.vim is <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, not lowercase s.

You can check whether it's defined with `:verbose vmap S`. Do the other surround.vim mappings (`ys`, `cs`, ...) work? If not, check `:scriptnames` and `:set runtimepath?` for troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, `S` is the correct mapping in visual mode.  See`:h surround-replacements`.  `s` is already mapped for visual mode, so `S` was chosen instead... (confusing at first)  See `:h v_s` for info on visual mode s operator.  Note there is a visual mode `S` by default too.  But because it is a synonym for visual `R`, the vim surround plugin overrides visual `S` with its surround command.

Comment: shift-s insert an additional space.How to avoid that?

Comment: I basically want it behave like as shown by [jeffrey way](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/vim-essential-plugin-surround/)

Comment: @deven98602 - Are you referring to the space inside the brackets? Because if so - use a left bracket if you want the additional space and a right bracket if you don't. e.g. `S[` will do `[ a ]`, and `S]` will do `[a]`.

Comment: I  have no idea what your answer is about. Highlighting line with "shift+v" then doing "shift+s" just goes to insert mode. I've installed this plugin with vundle. and what do you mean shift+S.. shift+s producing S.. totally confused.

Comment: for those who want lowercase s to work:  `vmap s S`.  note that this uses a recursive mapping which is generally bad practice.  i was hoping the plugin would expose a better way, but couldn't find it

Comment: not working for me, c is for change in vim. I want to quote the simple string, how should i do it then?

Answer (score 3):

This can also be a key binding collision with the yankstack plugin. To fix it, append `call yankstack#setup()` to your `.vimrc` file. For more info, see the [discussion](https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-yankstack/issues/9) on GitHub.