# editing latex in vim : how to change text to math mode

Tags: vim, latex, math-mode

I am using vim-latexsuite to edit a latex file. The text is originally from google doc and there are many math symbols not written in math mode.

I have to add `$` before and after each symbol. But that is painful. (Search/Replace does not work because some equation patterns are complicated.)

Is there a way that allows me to visually select the symbols or equestions using `Ctrl-V` in visual mode, then after pressing the key, the `$` can be automatically added before and after the visual selection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is any standard command for this, but you can use the [surround.vim](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-surround-vim/) plugin to do this:

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-surround-vim/

The command is `csW$` to surround the current text with $

Comment: I love surround.vim. Note if you already have a selection you can just key `s$` to surround with `$`. And since `c`, `s`, `W`, and `$` are all keyed with the left hand, I'd use `ysiw$` to surround the word the cursor is on with `$` (it has a nice back-and-forth drumming motion). Or combine either with a macro and you're set!

Comment: For me, it's not ``csW$`` but ``cSW$`` (note the capital S) to surround text with the dollar sign $. When erroneously using lower case ``s``, text gets deleted. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497990/vim-surround-not-working-for-me-s-key-deletes-instead-of-surrounds

Answer (score 3):

There actually *is* a standard command for this built into vim-latexsuite. See the vim-latex docs for macros [here.](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/download/latex-suite.html#latex-macros)

```
In addition the visual mode macros are provided:

    `(  encloses selection in \left( and \right)
    `[  encloses selection in \left[ and \right]
    `{  encloses selection in \left\{ and \right\}
    `$  encloses selection in $$ or \[ \] depending on characterwise or
                                          linewise selection
```

Answer (score 2):

You can record a macro to do this.

With a visual selection, do this:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> – record macro in register q

<kbd>c</kbd> – change the content of the visual selection

<kbd>$</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> – insert $$

<kbd>P</kbd> – paste the original text between the $s (note it's a capital P)

<kbd>q</kbd> – stop recording the macro

From then on, you can make your visual selection and just run <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.